# StackOverflowError on spetialized streams (IntStream/LongStream) usage for final field initialization

Tags: java, java-8, initialization, java-stream

Faced unexpected behavior while using stream to initialize static field:

```
public class TestCompilation {
    static final String message = "concatenation argument " + IntStream.range(0,42)
            .mapToObj(i -> i+",")
            .reduce((a, b)->a+b).get();      // StackOverflowError

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

The code above leads to `Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Can somebody explain the reason of such result?

---

javac 1.8.0_111 was used to compile java sources

Comment: I tried your code (including the commented out sections) and got no exceptions.

Comment: It would be worth clarifying that this is an error at *compilation* time, not at execution time - and ideally, *only* show the code that fails (rather than the code that's working, with the broken code commented out...)

Comment: @Eran: How did you compile it? I get the error at compile-time with javac.

Comment: @JonSkeet I compiled with Eclipse. I copied the code into an existing class, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Eran: Right, that doesn't surprise me - it sounds like it's a bug in javac which isn't in the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: I don't get any compile-time error nor runtime error (1.8.0_102).

Comment: @AlexisC. I overdid while cleaned up initial example, so code was compilable for a some time. Seems the concatenation with a stream usage result is a way to reproduce the error.

Comment: Looks related: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143898 // https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077605

Comment: @Tom: indeed, seems to be fixed in jdk1.9.0b066.